# Pytest Selenium elem.send_keys() causing TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: selenium, webdriver, pytest, sendkeys, pytest-selenium

I am trying to send data to a login textbox but when I use 'send_keys' I get an error..

```
def wait_for_element(selenium, selenium_locator, search_pattern, wait_seconds=10):
    elem = None
    wait = WebDriverWait(selenium, wait_seconds)

    try:
        if (selenium_locator.upper() == 'ID'):
            elem = wait.until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, search_pattern))
            )
    except TimeoutException:
        pass

    return elem

userid=os.environ.get('userid')
wait_for_element(selenium, "ID", 'username')
assert elem is not None
elem.click()
time.sleep(3)
elem.send_keys(userid)
```

> tests\util.py:123: in HTML5_login
>       elem.send_keys(userid)
>   ..\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:478: in send_keys
>       {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
>
> ---
>
> value = (None,)
>
> ```
> def keys_to_typing(value):
>     """Processes the values that will be typed in the element."""
>     typing = []
>     for val in value:
>         if isinstance(val, Keys):
>             typing.append(val)
>         elif isinstance(val, int):
>             val = str(val)
>             for i in range(len(val)):
>                 typing.append(val[i])
>         else:
>           for i in range(len(val)):
> ```
>
> > ```
> >          for i in range(len(val)):
> > ```
> >
> > E               TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

I have no clue why it is saying the element is of "NoneType" when I have it pass an assertion as well as click the element. I can even see it clicking the element when I run the test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
elem.send_keys(userid) ..\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:478: in send_keys {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)), value = (None,)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

...implies that `send_keys()` method encountered an error when sending the contents of the variable **userid**.

Though you have tried to use the variable **userid**, I don't see the variable **userid** being declared anywhere within your code block. Hence you see the error:

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

---

### Solution

Initialize the **userid** variable as:

```
userid = "Austin"
```

Now, execute your test.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to include userid within the code i posted. I can assure you tho that userid has a string set to it. Will update the post.

Comment: Actually this was the issue.. I was assigned userid to ```userid=os.environ.get('userid')```

Seems something is wrong with this piece of code, thank you for your help!